# esLint globals - define with regex or wildcard?

Tags: javascript, eslint, global

I am trying to use esLint in a Javascript file that is used as a source for SharePoint content editor webpart and I use an external JS library which is loaded elsewhere by the external solution itself. Therefore I don't need to import them in my files myself.

In my .eslintrc.js I want to specify the functions defined in the external library by a wildcard or regex, e.g. like this

```
'globals': {
  myLib_*: true
}
```

or

```
'globals': {
  /myLib_[^\s]+/: true
}
```

so calls of any function starting with myLib_ are not marked as `no-undef`

Is this possible or not? If it is not, I can put the external library on my filesystem and then reference it in the .eslintrc.js how?

Thank you!

Comment: were you able to find a solution for adding regex in globals for eslint? I am facing the same issue and hoping to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the closed issues below, it unfortunately looks like it won't be supported

ESLint contributer nzakas stated in [a comment in 2015](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4158#issuecomment-148757806) that

> Globals can't work with unknown values because we do full scope resolution, not just identifier name matching.

- [eslint/eslint#4158 — Regex support for globals](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4158)
- [eslint/eslint#12138 — Support regex for globals in config](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/12138)