# Eslint: Set pattern for global variables

Tags: eslint

We working with a form management system as a base for creating forms. It also includes some helper functions to interact with these forms.

One thing is the generation of global variables for each field like `$SURNAME`. It has always the same schema. Besides the problem that the list of global variables is very long, the name could also change. Therefore it will be a big effort to add and maintain them in the eslint config file.

I search for a way to define a pattern to ignore these variables from being checked without deactivating the whole `no-undef` rule.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713701/eslint-globals-define-with-regex-or-wildcard